# Rails 5 joins where clause on both tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I include a where clause on the `Reply` table with the following query?

```
Reply.joins(:replier_account).where(replier_accounts: {account_type: 'reply' })
```

I tried adding it at the end like so:

```
Reply.joins(:replier_account).where(replier_accounts: {account_type: 'reply' }).where("created_at > ?", 7.days.ago)
```

But I'm receiving the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "created_at" is ambiguous
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error tells you it doesn't know which table you want the 'created_at' to be filtered on (At a guess, they both have 'created_at'). Try affixing the table name to the created_at; like so:

```
Reply.joins(:replier_account)
     .where(replier_accounts: {account_type: 'reply' })
     .where("replier_accounts.created_at > ?", 7.days.ago)
```

Answer (score 2):

The other way to rewrite this query is to merge WHERE conditions into one call.

To fetch replies whose accounts were created in the last 7 days:

```
Reply.joins(:replier_account)
     .where(
        "replier_accounts.account_type = :type AND replier_accounts.created_at > :created_at",
        { type: 'reply', created_at: 7.days.ago }
     )
```

Or, to fetch replies which were created in last 7 days:

```
Reply.joins(:replier_account)
     .where(
        "replier_accounts.account_type = :type AND replies.created_at > :created_at",
        { type: 'reply', created_at: 7.days.ago }
     )
```